# How to build TkTreeCtrl on Windows 10 using VS 2019 tools?

Tags: visual-c++, tcl

I'm able to compile both Tcl and Tk just fine on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2019 developer command prompt.  Both have `win\makefile.vc` file. `nmake -f makefile.vc` will build them successfully.

However, TkTreeCtrl source code located at the following location doesn't seem to have `makefile.vc` anywhere.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/tktreectrl/files/tktreectrl/tktreectrl-2.4.1/tktreectrl-2.4.1.tar.gz/download

I had compiled TkTreeCtrl successfully several years ago.  But I can't for the life of me remember how I did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fork from https://github.com/apnadkarni/tktreectrl contains the makefile for the new Windows build system of Tcl.

Answer (score 0):

I have just successfully built it under windows10 with MSYS2/Mingw64 from the source https://github.com/apnadkarni/tktreectrl just as the suggestion of [@Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4800745/eric). But need some changes in `configure` to make it work.

for `tktreectrl\configure`

```
-   *win32*|*WIN32*|*MINGW32_*)
+   *win32*|*WIN32*|*MINGW32_*|*MINGW64_*)

-    vars="gdi32.lib user32.lib"
+    vars="gdi32.lib user32.lib UxTheme.lib"

-       RC_DEPARG='"$(shell $(CYGPATH) $<)"'
+       RC_DEPARG='"$<"'
```

for `tktreectrl\shellicon\configure`

```
-   *win32*|*WIN32*|*MINGW32_*)
+   *win32*|*WIN32*|*MINGW32_*|*MINGW64_*)

-       RC_DEPARG='"$(shell $(CYGPATH) $<)"'
+       RC_DEPARG='"$<"'
```

Then, you just need to `./configure && make install`